# Based on color and value fetching-Compiles but no output

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I am working on a dynamic worksheet which the total rows and columns of content will be changing.

What I try to do is, making an active cell going through the worksheet. It starts from the very last column that has content (I used `UsedRange` here), and from the 7st row down to the last row not blank.

When 1) The active cell has a color filling of index 16 or 36; 2) The active cell has no value, the cell will fetch the value storing in the matching row E.

The loop will end when hitting column E (I haven't been able to go that far yet).

I will attach my code below for all possible help, since it complies but does not return any result...Thank you again!

```
Sub catchCurrentAutomated()

    Dim column As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim Cell As Range

    row = 7
    column = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Set Cell = ActiveCell

      While range("A" & row) <> ""

        If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 16 And _
           IsEmpty(Cell.Value) = True Then

        Cell.Value = Cells(ActiveCell.row, "E").Value

        ElseIf Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36 And _
           IsEmpty(Cell.Value) = True Then

        Cell.Value = Cells(ActiveCell.row, "E").Value

        End If

        row = row + 1
        column = column - 1

      Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the cell coloring applied manually or is it due to conditional formatting?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks Tim! The coloring came from Oracle BI exported excel, and worked well for the previous version of code you helped me. So I assume it is recognized as manual applied at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested)

```vb
Sub catchCurrentAutomated()

    Dim col As Long '<< use Long not Integer
    Dim row As Long
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, indx

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    col = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row  'last occupied cell in ColA
    
    Do While col > 5
        For row = 7 To lr
            With ws.Cells(row, col)
                indx = .Interior.Color.Index
                If (indx = 16 Or indx = 36) And Len(.Value) = 0 Then
                    .Value = ws.Cells(row, "E").Value
                End If
            End With
        Next row
        col = col - 1 'next column to left
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim!! I made a little change and it works perfectly now!